# I would like to go back to a job I lost, does it make sense to apply at another staffing agency that is recruiting for the same company?

Tags: recruitment, applications, termination

I was working at a company through a local staffing agency, but lost the job mostly due to attendance issues. When I asked the agency about possibly getting my job back, I was told the company declined my return.

My question is, can I apply to the same company through a different agency? If so, is there a waiting period? I have a couple friends who have done this, but I don't know specifics.

Comment: "I was told the company declined my return" - you have answered your own question

Comment: "I have a couple friends who have done this, but I don't know specifics" - if they are friends, you can ask them, but maybe their circumstances were different, and "I was told the company declined my return" would seem to indicate that you have no hope. Best look elsewhere, and work on your attendance issues.

Answer (score 13):

Can you legally do so?  Sure.  But the company doesn't want you.  That's why they fired you, and declined to take you back.  Even if you slip through the cracks and get brought back in, they'd immediately fire you again.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can or not depends on any exclusivity of representation or non-compete clauses that were in your contract with the agency.

Beyond that, your name may be flagged as "do not rehire" in the system.  If so, even if you can, it may get you nowhere.  Best thing to do would be to move on.